# Why does click doesn't activate a link from the first time in chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, hyperlink, anchor

I have two anchors containing a div that has a transition on hover but it takes me some patience to actually open the link. And I can't figure why not.

I tried the same thing using a redirect to page with javascript on div, but I still have the same problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "take some patience"? You mean it's hard to click the <a> while it's rotating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#socialbuttons a {
    display: block; /*added*/
    height: 64px;
    width: 54px;
}
```

Adding display: block; the facebook link works,
then you have to fix the other class for nice display.

Finally: HTML 4.01 specifies that  elements may only contain inline elements. A  is a block element, so it may not appear inside an .

**EDIT**:

```
#socialbuttons div:first-child {
    margin-left: 20px /* REMOVE THIS */;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#socialbuttons a {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

remove (or put it on the anchor)

```
#socialbuttons div:first-child {
   margin-left: 20px;
}
```

now apply the hover rule to the surrounding anchor

```
#socialbuttons a:hover div {
...
}
```

I haven't tried this but this should solve the flickering when the div turns and is no longer under the cursor.
Let me know if this still does not work.

Answer (score -2):

I may have found the reason why Chrome + LastPass is behaving this way. 
I uninstalled Chrome and all it's extenssions.
Then installed an earlier version of Chrome, ver 13, and an earlier version of LastPass (1.9) with the LastPass Installer. 
I tired the Chrome extension route to install LastPass but it gave an error as it wanted the latest version of Chrome.
Don't know why but when I checked LastPass "About" it now shows 2.0.0 version. Did it upgrade itself?.
With that new combination the browser seems to working OK with external links. 
I say 'seems' as I have had immediate success with different browser/extension combinations only to have the browser revert back to problem with certin links and after so much usage: none of which I could identify. 
I'll monitor this setup for another couple of days and install a few other extentions.
If my susspicion holds it will be a problem not using the latest version of CHrome for security reasons and that I won't be able to install the latest extensions. Bummer.